# Index rows by date and include duplicate dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
ID       drug start date 
A           X 2019-11-16
A           Y 2018-11-16
A           Z 2020-11-16
B           X 2019-11-16
B           Y 2019-11-16
B           X 2020-11-16
C           X 2019-11-16
C           X 2020-11-16
```

I want to create a new column where all the drugs for each ID are numbered by date, but those that have the same start date have the same index. The drug name does not matter for indexing (ie, those starting on the same date have the same index). For example,

```
ID       drug start date order
A           X 2019-11-16     2
A           Y 2018-11-16     1
A           Z 2020-11-16     3
B           X 2019-11-16     1
B           Y 2019-11-16     1
B           X 2020-11-16     2
C           X 2019-11-16     1
C           X 2020-11-16     2
```

How do I create this new column? I have tried sorting then using `mutate(order=row_number())`, but it does not deal with the duplicate date issue. This is my first time posting a question on this forum, so thanks in advance for your help and please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Can you add what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` from `dplyr`, which allows for ties and next rank value after the tie is the next integer value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(order = dense_rank(`start date`))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID    drug  `start date` order
#>   <chr> <chr> <date>       <int>
#> 1 A     X     2019-11-16       2
#> 2 A     Y     2018-11-16       1
#> 3 A     Z     2020-11-16       3
#> 4 B     X     2019-11-16       1
#> 5 B     Y     2019-11-16       1
#> 6 B     X     2020-11-16       2
#> 7 C     X     2019-11-16       1
#> 8 C     X     2020-11-16       2
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `frank` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, order := frank(start_date, ties.method = 'dense'), ID]
df1
#   ID drug start_date order
#1:  A    X 2019-11-16     2
#2:  A    Y 2018-11-16     1
#3:  A    Z 2020-11-16     3
#4:  B    X 2019-11-16     1
#5:  B    Y 2019-11-16     1
#6:  B    X 2020-11-16     2
#7:  C    X 2019-11-16     1
#8:  C    X 2020-11-16     2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
    drug = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X"), 
     start_date = structure(c(18216, 
    17851, 18582, 18216, 18216, 18582, 18216, 18582), class = "Date")), 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```